# Getting elastic bean creation issue after upgrading HLRS to elastic client in spring boot app in java 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

Getting bean creation issue with java 17,spring boot 3.0 and Elastic Search 8.6
here is my client class which is used to initiate elastic connection:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.es.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.es","com.es.model","com.es.service","com.es.config" })

public class ESJavaClient
{
    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.url.noport}")
    private String urlWithoutPort;

    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.port}")
    private String port;

    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.protocol}")
    private String protocol;

    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.ssl.truststore.path}")
    private String truststorePath;

    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.ssl.truststore.password}")
    private String truststorePassword;

    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.ssl.keystore.path}")
    private String keystorePath;

    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.ssl.keystore.password}")
    private String keystorePassword;

    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.password}")
    private String password;

    private static ElasticsearchAsyncClient asyncClient;

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private RestClient restClient;

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchTransport transport;

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient;



    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient() {

        RestClient restClient = restClient();

        JacksonJsonpMapper jacksonJsonpMapper = new JacksonJsonpMapper();

        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, jacksonJsonpMapper);
        //asyncClient  = new ElasticsearchAsyncClient(transport);

        ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
        return elasticsearchClient;

    }

    @Bean
    public RestClient restClient() {
        return restClientBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder() {
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        
        HttpHost ht = new HttpHost(urlWithoutPort, Integer.parseInt(port), protocol);

        if (protocol != null && protocol.equalsIgnoreCase("https")) {
            return RestClient.builder(ht).setRequestConfigCallback(
                    requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(180000).setSocketTimeout(900000))
                    .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder
                            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).setSSLContext(getSSL()));
        }

        return RestClient.builder(ht)
                .setRequestConfigCallback(
                        requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(180000).setSocketTimeout(900000))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder);
    }

    /*@Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(elasticsearchClient);
    }*/

    /*@PreDestroy
    public void cleanup() {
        try {
            log.info("Closing the ES REST client");
            transport.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Problem occurred when closing the ES REST client", e);
        }
    }*/


    private SSLContext getSSL() {
        try {
            File key = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:keystore.jks");
            File trust = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:truststore.jks");

            return SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(key, keystorePassword.toCharArray(), keystorePassword.toCharArray())
                    .loadTrustMaterial(trust, truststorePassword.toCharArray()).build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("SSLContext set failed");
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }



}
```

2 Modelclass :

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestModelDTO {

    private String name;
    private String address;
}

Test Repositry Interface

@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<TestRepositoryModel, String>{

    public TestRepositoryModel findByName(String itemId);
}
```

4. TestRepositoryModel class

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(indexName = "#{@environment.getProperty('test.model.project.index')}")

public class TestRepositoryModel {

    @Id
    @Field(type= FieldType.Keyword)
    private String id;

    @Field(type= FieldType.Keyword)
    private String name;

    @Field(type= FieldType.Keyword)
    private String address;

}
```

When i start the server i am getting the below error

Spring not able to create beans for repository classes, I am getting bean creation issue, when include Repository related class in my project getting bean creation issue. I am using Intellij 2022.2.1.we have migrated java 11 to 17,spring boot from 2.5 to 3.0 and elastic search 7.7 to 8.6

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-08-09T17:10:57.275+05:30 ERROR 25004 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'testRepository': Error creating bean with name 'testRepository' defined in com.optum.bpa.es.repository.TestRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ESJavaClient: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
    at  co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:155) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.8.2.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.ElasticsearchIndicesClient.create(ElasticsearchIndicesClient.java:266) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.lambda$doCreate$0(IndicesTemplate.java:138) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ChildTemplate.execute(ChildTemplate.java:71) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [{Cluster-URL}:443], URI [/test-model-project], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]

    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

we tried below solution as temporary fix as elastic cluster upgrade to 8.16:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-compatibility.html

but we are moving elastic client as permanent fix. Can anybody please suggest solution for above error.